# Issue With PyUnity Installation

Tags: python, pip, pyunity

I am attempting to install pyunity and it keeps giving the error `Failed building wheel for pyunity`.

It says the issue is that `setuptools.installer and fetch_build_eggs are deprecated`. And to fix i need to run `pip install --use-pep517`.

I have tried `pip install --use-pep517 pyunity` and it gets rid of the first error but still includes the line:

```
src/loader.c:265:12: fatal error: 'longintrepr.h' file not found
```

I'm not sure how to fix this, I have already tried installing and updating all pyunity dependencies. I was using python 3.11.4 but then tried 3.9 as I think that is the latest version which supports pyunity. (When on the pypi package page https://pypi.org/project/pyunity/ it says python 3.6/3.7/3.8/3.9). I have also tried using VScode instead of Pycharm to install it and get the same error.

I have also tried cloning the github repository as an alternative way to install it but it didnt work.

When I ran:

```
> git clone https://github.com/pyunity/pyunity
> git checkout master
> python setup.py install
```

I got this output:

```
jameslandolt@Jamess-MacBook-Air PycharmProjects % git clone https://github.com/pyunity/pyunity
Cloning into 'pyunity'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 15068, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (2028/2028), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (663/663), done.
remote: Total 15068 (delta 1432), reused 1925 (delta 1331), pack-reused 13040
Receiving objects: 100% (15068/15068), 12.78 MiB | 1.67 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (10563/10563), done.
jameslandolt@Jamess-MacBook-Air PycharmProjects % git checkout master
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
jameslandolt@Jamess-MacBook-Air PycharmProjects % cd pyunity
jameslandolt@Jamess-MacBook-Air pyunity % git checkout master
branch 'master' set up to track 'origin/master'.
Switched to a new branch 'master'
jameslandolt@Jamess-MacBook-Air pyunity % python setup.py install
zsh: command not found: python
```

I am probably doing something dumb as I am not familiar with git.

Does anyone know how to fix this, btw I am on a Macbook Air?

The exact log for:

`pip install --use-pep517 pyunity`

is:

```
  Using cached pyunity-0.8.4.tar.gz (5.1 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: pyopengl in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from pyunity) (3.1.7)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from pyunity) (10.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pysdl2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from pyunity) (0.9.16)
Collecting pysdl2-dll (from pyunity)
  Using cached pysdl2_dll-2.28.4-py2.py3-none-macosx_10_11_x86_64.whl.metadata (4.3 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pyglm in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from pyunity) (2.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: glfw in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from pyunity) (2.6.3)
Using cached pysdl2_dll-2.28.4-py2.py3-none-macosx_10_11_x86_64.whl (5.0 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyunity
  Building wheel for pyunity (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for pyunity (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [80 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity
      copying src/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity
      copying src/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity
      copying src/notes.txt -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/scenes
      copying src/scenes/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/scenes
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/values
      copying src/values/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/values
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/primitives
      copying src/primitives/capsule.mesh -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/primitives
      copying src/primitives/double_quad.mesh -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/primitives
      copying src/primitives/quad.mesh -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/primitives
      copying src/primitives/cube.mesh -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/primitives
      copying src/primitives/sphere.mesh -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/primitives
      copying src/primitives/cylinder.mesh -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/primitives
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/window
      copying src/window/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/window
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/examples
      copying src/examples/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/examples
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/examples/example2
      copying src/examples/example2/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/examples/example2
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/examples/example5
      copying src/examples/example5/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/examples/example5
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/examples/example4
      copying src/examples/example4/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/examples/example4
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/examples/example3
      copying src/examples/example3/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/examples/example3
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/examples/example10
      copying src/examples/example10/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/examples/example10
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/examples/example6
      copying src/examples/example6/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/examples/example6
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/examples/example1
      copying src/examples/example1/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/examples/example1
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/examples/example8
      copying src/examples/example8/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/examples/example8
      copying src/examples/example8/logo.png -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/examples/example8
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/examples/example9
      copying src/examples/example9/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/examples/example9
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/examples/example7
      copying src/examples/example7/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/examples/example7
      copying src/examples/example7/explode.ogg -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/examples/example7
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/shaders
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/shaders/standard
      copying src/shaders/standard/fragment.glsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/shaders/standard
      copying src/shaders/standard/vertex.glsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/shaders/standard
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/shaders/gui
      copying src/shaders/gui/fragment.glsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/shaders/gui
      copying src/shaders/gui/vertex.glsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/shaders/gui
      copying src/shaders/gui/button.png -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/shaders/gui
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/shaders/gui/textures
      copying src/shaders/gui/textures/checkboxOff.png -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/shaders/gui/textures
      copying src/shaders/gui/textures/checkboxOn.png -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/shaders/gui/textures
      copying src/shaders/gui/textures/button.png -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/shaders/gui/textures
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/shaders/skybox
      copying src/shaders/skybox/fragment.glsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/shaders/skybox
      copying src/shaders/skybox/vertex.glsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/shaders/skybox
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/shaders/skybox/textures
      copying src/shaders/skybox/textures/bottom.jpg -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/shaders/skybox/textures
      copying src/shaders/skybox/textures/left.jpg -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/shaders/skybox/textures
      copying src/shaders/skybox/textures/top.jpg -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/shaders/skybox/textures
      copying src/shaders/skybox/textures/back.jpg -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/shaders/skybox/textures
      copying src/shaders/skybox/textures/right.jpg -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/shaders/skybox/textures
      copying src/shaders/skybox/textures/front.jpg -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/shaders/skybox/textures
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/physics
      copying src/physics/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyunity/physics
      running build_ext
      building 'loader' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/src
      clang -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11 -c src/loader.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/src/loader.o
      src/loader.c:265:12: fatal error: 'longintrepr.h' file not found
        #include "longintrepr.h"
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyunity
Failed to build pyunity
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyunity, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: what is your version of python?

Comment: I'm using python 3.9 as this is the latest that is supported by pyunity, I have tried with 3.11.4 and 3.12 and it gave the same error for all version.

Comment: I'm trying to edit your question to make it more readable but I'm unable to atm. Can you separate the error message from the rest of the question?

Comment: I'm also looking at the issue tracker for PyUnity and it says 'Functions are constantly being renamed, changed etc and it's better to have a constant API that contains deprecations which notify the user when certain functions will no longer be used.'

Comment: I have edited the question to be more readable, hopefully it is, I might be wrong but I don't think the issue is to do with pyunity's functions. For some reason it can't locate the 'longintrepr.h' file ```'longintrepr.h' file not found```. Apparently this issue was solved for someone when they installed python development headers so I looked up how to do this but apparently it is installed by default on mac.

Comment: I have been looking at your issue and strangely, I can't find similar problems online. I'd advice you raise an issue here https://github.com/pyunity/pyunity/issues

Comment: @journpy there are many issues about "missing" `longintrepr.h`, due to the fact that the file was moved in python3.11, so this looks like a python version issue, i.e. the library was not written for python 3.11

Comment: @JamesLandolt are you able to update your MacOS to 10.15?

Comment: @FlyingTeller that's why I changed my python version back to 3.9 but that didn't work. I will update my OS.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I updated my OS but can't get the latest as my mac is too old, from 2017, I have Monterey (Version 12.7.1) but that is the latest I can get and attempting to install pyunity I am getting the the same error. I am going away so I won't be able to respond for a while, thanks for the help tho.

Comment: Have you tried with python 3.9 and the new OS? pip should pick up a whl file for that config

Comment: @FlyingTeller I have tried with the new OS and it didn't work